# Is it a bug if my bag and my journal are contradicting?

Tags: pokemon-go

I challanged an eevee and when  I throw the ball immediately the fight ended. Now my journal tells me I caught it while it isn't in my bag and the pkedex entry for it is unrevealed aswell. Is there any reason for this happening or is it simply a bug?

Comment: it's probably a bug. niantic's servers aren't know for being very good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider it a bug. Due to the inconsistent stability of both the client and servers, I've had several Pokemon "eaten" where it says I've caught it but I can't find it in my list.